# Parse data file using Java

Tags: java, json, parsing

I have txt file formatted kinda like this:

```
*FIELD_NAME NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS
   ELEMENT
      *ANOTHER_FIELD NUMBER
         something
      #ANOTHER_FIELD
   ELEMENT
      *ANOTHER_FIELD NUMBER
         something
      #ANOTHER_FIELD
#FIELD_NAME
```

and I want to parse it using Java. This object might be similar to JSON

data sample:

```
*AAA 2
   1   FooBar
      *BBB  3
         101   2   
            Java
            Json
         102   2
            C++
            Another String
         103   1
            Stack
      #BBB
   2   BarFoo
      *BBB  2
         201   2
            over
            flow
         202   1
            it's the end of the file as we know it
      #BBB
#AAA
```

Appropriate structure to hold this data might be something like:

```
public class MyStruct {
   String name;
   List<MyStruct> elements;
}
```

but any ideas how to parse it?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using some parsing library to generate [AST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree).

Most popular in java are:

- [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/)
- [Xtext](https://eclipse.org/Xtext/)